# Memory limit exceeding in sub array problem

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

I'm trying to solve a problem, but I'm exceeding the memory limit.

Problem Description

Given an integer array A and two integers B and C.

You need to find the number of subarrays in which the number of occurrences of B is equal to number of occurrences of C.

NOTE: Don't count empty subarrays.

Input Format
First argument is an integer array A.

Second argument is an integer B.

Third argument is an integer C.

Output Format
Return an integer denoting the number of subarrays in which the number of occurrences of B is equal to number of occurrences of C.

```
/**
 * @input A : Integer array
 * @input n1 : Integer array's ( A ) length
 * @input B : Integer
 * @input C : Integer
 * 
 * @Output Integer
 */
int SubArrays(int* arr, int start, int end, int size, int B, int C)
{
   
    int countB = 0,countC = 0;
    // Stop if we have reached the end of the array
    if (end == size)
        return 0;
    
    // Increment the end point and start from 0
    else if (start > end)
        SubArrays(arr, 0, end + 1, size, B, C);
   
    // Print the subarray and increment the starting point
    else {
        int A[end-start+1];
        int i, j;
        for ( i = start; i < end; i++){
            for(j =0; j<(end-start+1);j++){
                A[j] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for(j =0; j<(end-start+1);j++){
            if(A[j]==B) countB ++;
            if(A[j]==C) countC ++;
        }
        // cout << arr[end] << "]" << endl;
        SubArrays(arr, start + 1, end, size, B, C);
    }
    if(countB == countC)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int solve(int* A, int n1, int B, int C) {
    int count = 0;
    count = count + SubArrays(A,0,0,n1,B,C);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: A comment like `@input B : Integer` doesn't really tell us much. What is the purpose of the argument variable? Why don't you give it a meaningful and descriptive name? Or if you use what's said in the assignment, why don't your comment give us some *actual* facts and information about what it's to be used for?

Comment: As a possible hint about your problem: When you call `SubArrays` recursively,  what happens with the value that the recursive call returns?

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You forgot to tell us what the problem with the shown code is, what efforts at debugging you have made, create a [mre] with hard-coded "input", and actually ask us a *question*.

Comment: i've included the problem statement in the text above. can you please read that?

Comment: You should not use recursion to solve this problem, and you should not create multiple auxiliary arrays. The problem can be solved in O(n log n) time: Create an auxiliary array (or can be done in place if the original array can be modified) S and put values in it such that S[i] equals the number of occurrences of B in A[0] through A[i], inclusive, minus the number of occurrences of C. Then, for every i and j such that i < j and S[i] equals S[j], the subarray from A[i] to A[j] has an equal number of occurrences of B and occurrences of C…

Comment: … And we can count those by sorting S and then processing the duplicates. For every run of n duplicate values in S, there are n•(n−1)/2 pairs that can formed from it. E.g., if 4 appears 3 times in S, then 3•(3−1)/2 = 3 subarrays can be formed from them. (E.g., if 4 appeared at positions 1, 7, and 10, then the subarrays from 1 to 7, 7 to 10, and 1 to 10 each contain an equal number of occurrences of B and occurrences of C.)

Comment: You have described the problem you're supposed to solve, which is good. But what is the problem with the actual code you show? What happens when you build it *yourself* with extra warnings enabled? What happens when you run it *yourself*? What *should* happen? Again, please take some time to read or refresh the links I provided, to help you write better questions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “You forgot to tell us what the problem with the shown code is”: That is in the title, “Memory limit exceeding…,” and the first sentence, “… I'm exceeding the memory limit.”

Comment: I would argue that this is a combinatorics problem first. Once you have the answers as formulas, then it's a programming problem to actually calculate the results. Maybe you should ask the maths site first for the formula, if you can't figure it out or find it yourself, then try to code the solution.

Comment: Does the array A represent an ordered list? So the sub-arrays you mention must also be sublists of that ordered list? Suppose A = (3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1) then if B=3 C=4 how many times would you say (3, 4, 5, 2, 1) is a valid sub array?

Comment: @SimonGoater it should be two as per the question.

Comment: @SimonGoater i know the logic, it is exceeding memory space, so that's the reason I'm asking the question here.

Comment: I don't think it's clear why the answer you're expecting is two.

Comment: Just calling SubArrays(...) doesn't do anything. Do you mean return SubArrays(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, your routine creates an array `int A[end-start+1]` and then calls itself recursively. This uses a lot of space, and there is no need for it.

Many of the challenge or online judge problems are intended to be solved creatively, using a “greater” view of the problem and not “brute force” such as examining all possible combinations.

In this case, a solution is:

- Create an auxiliary array T and set each element T<sub>*i*</sub> to the number of times that *B* appears in the elements of *A* from A<sub>0</sub> to A<sub>*i*</sub> minus the number of times that *C* appears in the elements of *A* from A<sub>0</sub> to A<sub>*i*</sub>, inclusive. For example, with *B* = 3 and *C* = 4 and A as shown below:

| *i* | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| T | 0 | +1 | +2 | +2 | +1 | +1 | 0 | −1 | −2 |

- Then use T to find subarrays. For any *i* and *j* such that T<sub>*i*</sub> = T<sub>*j*</sub>, the subarray of A from A<sub>*i*</sub> to A<sub>*j*</sub>, inclusive, will contain equal numbers of *B* values and *C* values.
- You can count these by simply iterating through all *i* and *j* values in bounds with *i* ≤ *j*.

For example, with the above, (0, 6) (meaning *i*=0, *j*=6) forms a subarray with equal numbers of *B* values and *C* values, and so do (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), and (4, 5). So the desired number of subarrays is 5.

(If it modifying the original array is allowed, this auxiliary information can be computed in-place in the array, replacing its original contents.)

That will give you a solution that takes time roughly proportional to *n*<sup>2</sup>, where *n* is the number of elements in A. However, there is a better solution:

- Sort *T*. This puts all identical values together. Then you can iterate through *T* and easily count how many times each value occurs. For a value that occurs *m* times, *m*•(*m*−1)/2 pairs of *i* and *j* values can be formed from it, so add *m*•(*m*−1)/2 to a running total. At the end of iterating through T, the total is the desired number of subarrays.

That gives you an solution with a running time roughly proportional to *n* log *n*.

It can be implemented in one function with seven lines of C code (taking advantage of some C notations that an experienced programmer might use, but reasonable) and an auxiliary function (for the sort comparison) that is one or two lines.

Hint for counting the pairs: You do not need to wait until the end of a sequence of repetitions to add to the running total. If the current value in T has been seen *m* times so far, add *m*−1 to the running total. When the value has been seen *m* times, *m*•(*m*−1) will have been added for them. For example, if a value is seen four times, we will add 0 the first time it is seen, then 1, then 2, then 3, and 1+2+3 = 4•(4−1)/2.